# Django Filter model by Day of Date

Tags: mysql, django, filter, model, timezone

I am at a loss.  What I'm doing is very simple and works in dev but not prod.

I have a model, EmailLog, which contains a DateTimeField with a default of timezone.now.  Model is created in database with the correct timestamp.

I would like to display any models that were created today.

Model Snippet

```
class EmailLog(models.Model):
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     ...
```

Model shows in database as `2023-05-10 16:31:34.381` for created_on and a raw print(log.created_on) shows `2023-05-10 16:31:34.381741+00:00`

I'm attempting to pull logs for today like so

```
logs = list(EmailLog.objects.filter(created_on__day=10, created_on__month=5))
```

This works perfectly fine in dev, in production I'm given no results but also no errors.

I've tried `created_on__date=timezone.now().date()`, `created_on__gte=timezone.now().date()`, also tried various forms of the date in string ISO format `2023-05-10`, I've tried `created_on__range=(start_date,end_date)` where start_date is `2023-05-10 00:00:00` and end_date is `2023-05-10 23:59:59` and I get nothing.

Both dev and prod database are MySQL, but quite possibly different versions as the production app is in Azure using an Azure MySQL.  That is the only difference I can see between app deployments, both are using a virtual env, both configured with some packages, all managed with poetry and identical.

I'm at a loss, please point out the bonehead mistake I'm making.

Comment: Did you set `USE_TZ` to `True`?

Comment: related: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/can-not-extract-filter-a-date-time-field-when-time-zones-are-enabled.html Might be not really a mistake on your side, is more that MySQL sometimes "ships" without any knowledge of timezones. Disclosure: I'm the author of the article.

Comment: Yes, USE_TZ is True sorry for leaving that out

Comment: Interesting article, I'll take a closer look that def could be a difference, thanks Willem, I'll let you know

Comment: Willem, that was it, would you kindly offer that article/advice in a Answer so that I may give you credit as the answer?  Your article led me to look up how to enable the timezones on Azure MySQL which is this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-server-parameters#working-with-the-time-zone-parameter).  But ultimately you are the king!  Thanks so much, if you answer via the normal method I'll mark you as such!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this article](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/can-not-extract-filter-a-date-time-field-when-time-zones-are-enabled.html), MySQL uses (well what would it use otherwise) a table to store the timezones and how these are converted.

For some reason, this table might be truncated, and thus the conversion to a different timezone fails. It is a bit sad that the database then returns `NULL`, and does not raise some error.

Anyway, a system usually has some tools to list the timezones. In Unix/Linux systems for example, that data is contained in the `tz-info` package of most package managers. Files are then stored in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory to specify how these timezones are defined.

Azure MySQL databases have a stored procedure that can inspect the timezones on the system, and then fill the corresponding tables with information regarding these timezones. You can do this in a MySQL session with:

```
mysql> CALL mysql.az_load_timezone();
```

You might even want to run this command every now and then, to let the timezones keep in sync. Every now and then the specifics of some timezones change (slightly). MySQL will not look for the conversion to the data stored in the system, but in its tables.